# Mobile Safari - Input field submit button

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I notice when you go to google.com for example, the input field keyboard has a "submit" button as opposed to the original "return" button.
How do I turn on that feature?
I tried type=search but I still see the return button.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 6):

It actually works.
Need to have the form tag, I initially only had the input field.

Comment: I could't get this solution to work on iOS 6. [Here is the solution that works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864167/show-search-button-in-iphone-ipad-safari-keyboard/11254336#11254336)