# How to change the text of the "Go" button on iPhone virtual keyboard in Safari?

Tags: iphone, html, safari

I know this is easy in Cocoa. Not sure if it is possible in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change safari. It's not possible.

Comment: This, while accepted as the answer, is inferior to @mynameistechno's answer.

Answer (score 13):

That's not entirely accurate. Upon some research I discovered that if you set the input's type attribute to "search" for example, the Go button will read "Search":

[Mobile Safari - Input field submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990619/mobile-safari-input-field-submit-button)

This is visible in mobile Yahoo and mobile Google.