# Is there a way to label the Go button in iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, forms, web, mobile-safari

When focus is placed into an input of this form, iPhone shows input keyboard and Go button, which acts as submit. Is it possible to change the label to e.g. "Create"? I tried value, title or name but none of those work.

```
<form>
  <input name="foo" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create" title="Create"/>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the text of the "Go" button on iPhone virtual keyboard in Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233071/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-go-button-on-iphone-virtual-keyboard-in-safari)

Answer (score -1):

No, something like this is not possible.

Comment: Altough it's worth mentioning that "Go" **can be changed into "Search"** if the text field is type="search".

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233071/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-go-button-on-iphone-virtual-keyboard-in-safari

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990619/mobile-safari-input-field-submit-button