# Show 'Search' button in iPhone/iPad Safari keyboard

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, safari

I've noticed navigating in websites like Dell or Google, that typing in their search text box with iPhone, in the keyboard appears a blue button 'Search' instead of the standard 'Go' button that appears on any normal form.

What should you do to display the search button?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can influence this behaviour with:

```
<input type="search" />
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/exibi3/2)

Ignore the `submit` button's text being 'kettle,' I just wanted to be sure that it wasn't the submit button influencing the text of the iOS keyboard...

This is, of course, backwards compatible since a browser that doesn't understand `type="search"` will default to `type="text"`, which is useful for creating [forward-planning html5 forms](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/new-form-features-in-html5/).

Comment: Any idea why it works on this site though?
http://www.mobilecityonline.com/

Checked source on iPhone, and it is not using input with type=search.

Comment: To answer my own comment, it seems iPhone also displays "Search" on the keyboard if the name of the textbox also contains the word "search" in it.
Havent tested Android.

Comment: The `id` of the element had to contain search to make it work in Chrome, then to make it work on iPhone and iPad, I had to place the `input` within a `<form>`.

Comment: That form also needs to have the `action` attribute. I have tested this on iOS 9.3.1

Answer (score 110):

having *type="search"* is usually all you need to make software Search keyboard appear however in iOS8 it is mandatory to have a wrapping form with **action** attribute.

So the following code would have a software keyboard with “Return” button

```
<form>
    <input type="search" />
</form>
```

But this code should have blue “Search” button instead

```
<form action=".">
    <input type="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Setting `type=search` has negative UX side effect in Chrome iOS of rounding search input field corners. Hate when browsers start making UI design decisions for me.

Comment: @demisx you can (and probably always should) reset default browser styling in your CSS:
`[type="text"],
[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}`
and don't mix functionality with styling.

Comment: This should be the correct answer because, for whatever inane reasons, Apple doesn't give you the Search mask unless you include the form's action attribute.Without it, the type attribute is moot.

Comment: @Stonetip This answer came years later, likely as an updated solution when iOS 8 added the requirement to have an `action` attribute for the "Search" label to display on the on-screen keyboard.  So by today's standards, definitely a better answer, but not necessarily when the question was posed in early 2011.

Comment: are the any issues (in any browser) with this action="."?

Comment: Answer is still valid for iPhone 12.

Answer (score 30):

I was not able to get the search button with

```
<input type="search" />
```

However, I did get it to appear with

```
<form>
    <input name="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Not only name="search", but also just containing the word "search" is good enough. For example, name="archive_search"

Comment: I couldn't get the search keyboard to show up until my input field was surrounded by a form element. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: iOS 9.3.1 seems to need the `action` attribute for the search button to show up.

Answer (score 6):

In HTML5 standard, adding `enterkeyhint` attribute on the input is the proper way to change the label on the virtual keyboard

```html
<input enterkeyhint="search" />
```

> If no enterkeyhint attribute is provided, the user agent might use contextual information from the inputmode, type, or pattern attributes to display a suitable enter key label (or icon).

See [MDN Docs about `enterkeyhint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint)

Comment: See [WebKit change](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/251720/webkit) for details.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 8 you can enable the blue "Search"-button on the keyboard by doing one of:

- add input name=search
- add input type=search
- add id to input with the case sensitive word "search" in the ID, for
  example the-search or thesearchgod

Comment: did not work for me - had to use @Anton Bielousov solution from above with form action.

Answer (score 2):

When using @Anton Bielousov suggested solution, this also changes the styling of Android Devices. To counter this I had to:

- Add form around input.
- Add type="search"
- Add name containing search
- Add styling to counter the unwanted android styling

Android styling:

```css
input[type=search] { -webkit-appearance: none; }
/* clears the ‘X’ from Internet Explorer */
input[type=search]::-ms-clear { display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=search]::-ms-reveal { display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
/* clears the ‘X’ from Chrome */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

```html
<form action="" class="search-bar__form-form">
  <input
    class="search-bar__input"
    name="search-bar"
    type="search"
  />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The keyboard is handled by the operating system (iOS) and cannot be directly altered. The type of input required determines the type of keyboard to display.

If the website in question is HTML5, then @David's answer is valid.