# is there any way to submit a form from <textarea> on return key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a feedback `form`, the last input being a `textarea`.
Id like the enter/return/ 'go' key to send the form, is there a way to do this? (**for mobile**)

I'm currently detecting forms being sent with:

```
$('#feedback-form').on('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.which === 13) {
        checkFeedBackForm()
    }
})
```

This works for the input type text inputs (name + email) currently

***EDIT:***

This currently works for desktop, however I would like it to submit on mobile too.
Currently the 'go' button doesn't show up for mobile, only a 'return' button.

Comment: Have you tried placing your `keypress` event handler on the `textarea` directly?

Comment: Enter key for mobile ?

Comment: what if you just in you `if` statement do - `$('#feedback-form').submit();` ?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea from a usability standpoint. what if they want to go to the next line?

Answer (score 2):

The `textarea` is most likely "eating" your keypress events, so they don't bubble up to the form. Try attaching your `keypress` event directly to the `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a text input field instead of a textarea?
It handles natively the return action

if you want the 'search' or 'go' button use the 'search' type:
[Show 'Search' button in iPhone/iPad Safari keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864167/show-search-button-in-iphone-ipad-safari-keyboard)