# Show Search button on iOS keyboard using html input type=search in AngularJS app

Tags: ios, angularjs, safari, keyboard

In iOS 8 and above, to show the Search button on the iOS keyboard, you use the action attribute in the form. From Anton's answer here  ... [Show 'Search' button in iPhone/iPad Safari keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864167/show-search-button-in-iphone-ipad-safari-keyboard)

```
<form action=".">
  <input type="search" />
</form>
```

But this does not work when you are using an AngularJS form with ng-submit like this

```
<form action="." ng-submit="doSearch(searchtext)">
  <input type="search"  ng-model="searchtext"  />
</form>
```

The action attribute breaks the Angular form submit.

Any suggestions on how to put a dummy action attribute and still get ng-submit to handle the form processing? Or any other solution that would show the iOS keyboard's search key with an AngularJS HTML5 form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just encountered the same problem, key here is that `angular` prevents default `form` submission only if no `action` specified, so if you want to specify one you need to `preventDefault` manually, which should be pretty easy.

This should work (worked for me):

```
<form action="." ng-submit="$event.preventDefault();doSearch(searchtext)">
  <input type="search"  ng-model="searchtext"  />
</form>
```

Also note, that you will need to `blur()` your input field after you made a Search request in order to auto-hide keyboard.

**Update:**

With the latter this directive will help you:

```
.directive('prettySubmit', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        var textFields = $(element).children('input');

        $(element).submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();                
            textFields.blur();
        });
    };
})
```

I have placed `preventDefault()` in directive, so your `form` will look like this:

```
<form action="." ng-submit="doSearch(searchtext)" pretty-submit>
  <input type="search"  ng-model="searchtext"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome. Tested this out and it works great! Thanks Max

Comment: Defocusing element would mean decrease in UX though - if user wants to search something again using just keyboard

Comment: @ArtjomKurapov I would argue with that, it's a matter of tradeoffs, keyboard will take up half of a screen so user will usually want to get it out of the way to see what results this search returned.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem.
Finally I decided to use

<form action="{{'#/search/' + searchText }}">

Instead, and it works.