# How to stop "Go" button being replaced with "Next" - Chrome Android Browser App

Tags: android, html, forms, google-chrome

I have a very detailed and very long/large ordinary **html** search input form with keyword text-input, price range min/max, and many, many other search criteria.

Submit button is present, but it is all the way down at the end of the form.

```
<form action="http://..." method="get" class="some-class" onsubmit="">
<fieldset class="box options">
    <input type="text" name="pattern" id="pattern" placeholder="pattern" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" placeholder="region" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="country" name="country" placeholder="country" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="price-min" name="price-min" placeholder="min" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="price-max" name="price-max" placeholder="max" value="" />
    (etc...)
    <button id="search-submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, my problem is completely the opposite of what I've seen in the questions/issues here and searching around the web. Most had the opposite issue trying to actually get **Next** instead of **Go**, but I need the reverse (or old) behavior. Instead of new **Next** while "inside" (in focus) on each text input fields above, I would like to see good old simple **Go**.

Why? Because, these inputs are not data-dependent, each input in the form can be provided separately.

It is probably a relatively recent change in Chrome Android browser (currently tested latest Chrome App for Android 62.0.3202.84) and potentially few other browsers/mobile OS apps. But, it was not like this before, that's for sure.

I wish we had a way to stop this behavior and manually instruct mobile browsers or virtual keyboards how they should behave, as it is really annoying to have **Next** in a massive search filter form, where someone just wants to fill in first or few initial inputs like keyword and press **Go**, because in long forms submit button is all the way down.

Does anyone have any idea how can we fix this, without re-inventing my entire form?

Thanks

Comment: There is one very very ugly solution I'm thinking of: to split my form in 2 (or N smaller parts), and then clone all the other field values with javascript, so, whichever form (scenario) user does, all relevant parameters will be saved in all of them and form will work overall as original one. But, I don't like it much, as it is really "hackish" solution in nature.

Comment: Another, much more acceptable idea (but still not true solution), is to simply clone submit button near the top after "priority" inputs, so the users can simply click on submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue and the solution I found was to simply set `type="search"` instead of `type="text"` on the inputs.

Inspired from: [Show 'Search' button in iPhone/iPad Safari keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864167/show-search-button-in-iphone-ipad-safari-keyboard)

Comment: I've completely forgotten this question to be honest. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, this "issue" (behavior) affects only input type="text" fields, if the form has other types like check boxes and drop down lists, they are ignored from the next-next-next, adding further inconsistency/annoyance. Marking your answer as accepted!