# Validate fields using JQuery validation without any submit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a HTML5 web application with numerous user-entered fields, and I would like to do some client-side validation on those fields in javascript before sending them to the server. Easy right? Just use JQuery validation plugin --- http://jqueryvalidation.org/

But there's a catch. My web app has no forms. There is no submit anywhere in the HTML. Instead there's a JQuery change handler on every user-changeable element, and when the user changes the value of one of those element, an AJAX call is made. (This nonstandard user interaction architecture makes sense for this application.)

I would like to validate the field before the AJAX call, and use the JQuery validation plugin to do that. But I can't figure out how.

Is it possible to use the JQuery validation plugin without a submit anywhere? How would I do this? Or is another approach better?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Firstly**, and most importantly, you ***must*** wrap your input elements inside `<form></form>` tags for the jQuery Validate plugin to operate.  However, a submit button is not required.

**Secondly**, you can programatically trigger the validity test of any or all elements without a submit button by using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin on your form.
        // rules, options, and/or callback functions
    });

    // trigger validity test of any element using the .valid() method.
    $('#myelement').valid();

    // trigger validity test of the entire form using the .valid() method.
    $('#myform').valid();

    // the .valid() method also returns a boolean...
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        // something to do if form is valid
    }

});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/URQGG/

Answer (score 3):

You will have to wrap your fields within a form to use the validation plugin and it's a [good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309214/why-use-a-form-tag-when-youre-submitting-via-ajax) anyway. Also, you can invoke the plugin's validation programmatically and check if the form is valid by doing:

```
var $form = $('#your_form'),
    validator = $form.validate({...});

//validate the form
validator.form();

//check if the form is valid 
if ($form.valid()) {
    //form is valid
}
```

For more options, have a look at the [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: What is the purpose of assigning the object to a variable?  An additional line to save a couple characters seems verbose when you can simply call `$('#your_form').validate()` and `$('#your_form').valid()`.  (Also, you don't need to call `validator.form()` at all.)

Comment: @Sparky, there are several methods that can only be invoked on the validator returned from the `validate` function, so it's a good idea to keep a reference to it if needed. Also, it's a bad practice to always requery the DOM for getting elements referenced multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but in this case there is an available method called `.valid()` that eliminates the need to keep track of `.validate()`.  Also, I'm just not sure that the benefit of jQuery not looking in the DOM a second time is worth the 40+ extra characters.  Anyway, I suppose we're splitting hairs as there is nothing technically wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a little helper. Just add this line of code and then you can use any button anywhere.

```
$("body [data-submit-form]").on("click", function (event) {
    $("#" + $(event.target).data('submit-form')).valid();
});

<form id="component-form">

</form>

<button data-submit-form="component-form">Button</button>
```

Explanation: The jquery code listens for all clicks on an element with the attribute 'data-submit-form', in the listener the data-attribute gets extracted and then i trigger the valid method on the matching form.

NOTE: if you want to submit the form if the form is valid use this code:

```
$("body [data-submit-form]").on("click", function (event) {
    var form = $("#" + $(event.target).data('submit-form'));
    if (form.valid()) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for two sample fields email and password:-

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #txt1{

        margin-left:23px;
        border-radius: 12px;
       }
       #txt2{
        border-radius: 12px;
       }
       #btn1{
        border-radius: 12px;
        width: 8em;  height: 2em;
        cursor:pointer;
        background-color: #008CBA;
       }
       #lbl1,#lbl2{
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        color:red;
       }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <center> <label id="lbl1">Email: </label><input type="text" id="txt1"></center></input><br>
            <center><label id="lbl2">Password: </label><input type="password" id="txt2"></center></input>
            <br><br>
            <center><input type="button" id="btn1" name="btn1" value="Login" style="color:darkblue;font-size:15px;"></center></input>
        </form>

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                var email = $('#txt1').val();
                var pass = $('#txt2').val();
                if (email == '') {
                    $('input[type="text"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
                    $("#txt1").parent().after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-left:93px;'><center>Please enter email address</center></div>");
                    alert("hi");
                }
                else {

                }
                if (pass == '') {
                    $('input[type="password"]').css("border", "2px solid red");
                    $("#txt2").parent().after("<div class='validationp' style='color:red;margin-left:70px;'><center>Please enter password</center></div>");
                }
                $('input[type="text"]').keydown(function () {
                    $('input[type="text"]').css("border", "");
                    $(".validation").remove();
                });
                $('input[type="password"]').keydown(function () {
                    $('input[type="password"]').css("border", "");
                    $(".validationp").remove();

                });

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

Just call the form submit method using `jquery`

```
$("#formId").submit()
```

This will validate entire form, same as when we click the submit button

Comment: OP: There are no form!