# Angular input validity property without a form

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have inputs in a web page without the form tag (useless to me).
How can I get their validity status inside the HTML ? This

```
<input name="myInput" type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{13}$/">
<input type="button" ng-show="myInput.$valid">
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that won't work without wrapping it in a form as you need to access those fields via the form's controller.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{13}$/">
    <input type="button" ng-show="myForm.myInput.$valid">
</form>
```

Should work.

If you're unable to use the `form` tag for any reason, you'll have to wire that up manually.

Comment: For another good reason to use the form tag, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6309420/957731) answer. Forms have semantic value even if the data is sent using AJAX.

Comment: Interesting comment but in my case the page is sufficiently complex for the enter key not to mean anything. If I had to manage that key manually, I wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Ivarni, in the example you provided, the form is not connected to a controller. To access myForm.myInput.$valid, do I need to precise ng-controller="myFormController" and implement an empty controller in the javascript code or is there some default controller automatically created by Angular?

Comment: No, Angular overrides the `form` element with a directive, so once you use `<form>` tag a FormController is created automatically. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: More specifically, "If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name." This is what lets you dot your way in to access the `$valid` property.