# Do I still need a Form element when using a AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

This might be a silly question but it is really matter to me to know if we really STILL need to wrap our input elements in side a `<form>` even when we are using jQuery Ajax to Pass and Retrieve data from the Server or Database?

I mean while Ajax method has options like type , url, data, and even dataType like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"process.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: "JSON"
});
```

Do we still need the Form? From the Security aspect I think we can validate the user inputs without having the form element but I am not sure that it correct or not?!
If you think we still need the Form so how we should deal with Form attributes like `action` and `method`? should we leave them blank?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to support clients that do not support JavaScript. If no, do what you like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use a form tag when you're submitting via ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309214/why-use-a-form-tag-when-youre-submitting-via-ajax)

Comment: I don't understand why you _wouldn't_ use a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to wrap input (or other) elements in form tags when using ajax.

However, there are times when using a form construct is a good idea, such as if you want to use `.serialize()` to grab all the form names/values in one go *(for example, if you are using ajax - it's a great shortcut)*.

*Note that* if you use a form (i.e. submit button `<input type="submit"`) then you should also know that you can use `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` in your event code if you need to prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page. For example:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
    let validation_okay = true;
    //do your validation
    if (!validation_okay){
        alert('Please fix errors and re-submit');
        return false;
        //Here, form will NOT submit but will return control to user
    }
    //if form gets to here, it will submit normally
});
```

Everyone has their own style, but these days I rarely (if ever) use form tags and instead use jQuery/js to control the UX myself. With AJAX, there is really no need to use a form - you can do exactly the same thing *without navigating away from the current page (unless you then specifically code it to do so).*

BUT if you are set on using forms, also note that you can create a form tag on the fly, add it to the DOM, and use jQuery/js to submit it:

```
//You have a structure that is constructed WITHOUT any form tags - a lightbox or something
//The *submit* button is just an ordinary button (without `type="submit"`)
//User clicks your "Go" or "Submit" button, and you validate the field values. Now you
//want to submit it.
if (!validation_okay){
    let uid = $('#userid').val();
    let pwd = $('#pword').val();
    let myform = '\
        <form id="laform" action="process_login.php" action="post">\
            <input name="user_id" value="' + uid + '" />\
            <input name="passwrd" value="' + pwd + '" />\
        </form>';
    $('body').append(myform);
    $('#laform').submit();
}
```

***Or*** you can do the same thing as above using ajax, which would look like this:

```
let uid = $('#userid').val();
let pwd = $('#pword').val();
if (uid.length && pwd.length){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: '../ajax/login.php',
        data: 'lname=' + uid + '&pword=' + pwd
    }).done(function(d){
        console.log('Received back from PHP side: ' + d);
    });
}
```

On the PHP side, you would have a document here:

```
/public_html/ajax/login.php  
(Note: above code also expects your js file to also be in a subfolder, 
 for e.g. /public_html/js/script.js)
```

The PHP side might look something like this:

```
<?php
    $login_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $password = $_POST['pword'];
    if ($login_name == 'bob' && $password == 'baluga'){
        echo 'Login successful';
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong, wrong, wrong! Just wrong!'
    }
```

Reference:

[Why use a form tag when you're submitting via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309214/why-use-a-form-tag-when-youre-submitting-via-ajax)

Answer (score 3):

When using Ajax, the form serves several purposes. It provides:

- a way for the user to submit the data to the server when the JavaScript fails for any reason
- a convenient DOM interface to the controls inside it (`formElement.elements.field_id_or_name`)
- a semantic grouping that is (for example) used by screen reader software
- handling for the pressing of the enter key to trigger the submit event across all the fields

You don't *strictly* need it unless you want a robust, accessible, usable page without much more effort.

Comment: Not to mention the semantic value of marking up a form as a `form`.