# when to use form tags

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I'm working on a page which has an input and a button to add input somewhere to the page using jquery . is it valid to strip form tags and only use input and button tags?

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<button type="button" id="add-me">add</button>
```

JQuery :

```
$('#add-me').click(function(){
//do stuff
});
```

Comment: Are you interested in the validity according to the standard, or if it works in browsers?

Comment: It makes it easier to `submit` (send to the server) multiple `input` values at once. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it without the `form tag`. It's like making a group of `input`s :)

Comment: @Glubus yes. I'm interested in designing **standard** html pages

Comment: one option might be collect the input value then you can send via ajax

Comment: In that case I would recommend trying this stuff out in a html5 validator. I'm actually not sure if the standard restricts input tags to only exist within form tags, though you can easily check this by just giving it as input to a validator over njah https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options.

Comment: Wait is the question a normal yes or no question or do you want an explanation of how your button and textfield is suppose to work? This question looks to me like you want to know if it's valid like this.

Comment: I think sending form fields without form tag is possible, but it should be avoided

Comment: Personal opinion: A website should always be completely usable without JavaScript, JS should only be used to enhance the experience. With that in mind, form tags can never be omitted.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Good comment. Never actually thought about that myself but that sounds like a good mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can strip the `form` tag for showing standard things like that in jQuery. However your question is also tagged php which makes me think you do need it eventually.

Additionally I see a `text` tag. You can show the text without form as well but it wont *submit* it anywhere. You can show the input of the textfield with javascript/jQuery.

So for jQuery there is no real reason for `form` tags. However read this question: [Why use a form tag when you're submitting via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309214/why-use-a-form-tag-when-youre-submitting-via-ajax)